# Remix: 0x0 Transaction mined but execution failed due to construction

Tags: remix, constructor

I have the following example smart contract, where I cannot deploy using `remix` into my private network using environment `Web3 provider`. The error I am getting is `Transaction mined but execution failed due to construction`.

*Please note,* that my actual smart contract takes around 6.500.000 gas to deploy. I can deploy it if its constructor is empty, but I cannot if I set a storage variable in the constructor like I shown on the example.

**Update:** I am able to deploy my contract using `solidity ^0.5.0` but higher versions does not work.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.7;

contract Contract {
    address public owner;
    constructor() public
    {
        owner = msg.sender;     
    }

    function set() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
}
```

Transaction receipt:

[image]

---

When I comment out `owner = msg.sender;` the contract deploys successfully. But later if I call the `set` function, I get `Gas estimation failed` warning message and the `set()` does not deploy.

[image]

When I call the `set()` function warning message:

[image]

Comment: What is your `gasLimit` parameter? Only can reproduce your error with optimization enabled.

Comment: I have set `gas limit` as 8000000 @alberto

Comment: remix has a lot of bugs

Comment: I've tested with a private blockchain (geth) setting differents `gaslimit` and the problem is related with the optimization option of the old layout. I don't know why, but Remix try to spend all the available gas of the block with the optimization enabled (doesn't matter how much gas you've set in the `gaslimit`). With the new layout everything goes well with optimization enabled or disabled. Also tested with Truffle and the contract was deployed correctly with optimization and without it.

Comment: I am having same error on the remix's new interface as well for main contract to deploy 6.500.000 gas and if constructor is empty it is deployed @alberto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Update: I am able to deploy my contract using solidity ^0.5.0 but higher versions does not work.

Is your private network using the Constantinople EVM? If you can deploy 0.5.0 but not 0.5.7, you might be on Byzantium.  In Remix, on the compiler tab, try changing the EVM version from "compiler default" to "Byzantium" and see if you're able to deploy successfully.

Comment: My private chain uses `Byzantium EVM`, I am able to deploy successfully when I made the change as you recommended @iamdefinitelyahuman

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly for me using Remix (compile 5.10) and parity private network.
[image]

Try to enable/disable optimization it might help you.

### [image]

Comment: you can enable optimization in the new remix. you have to activate solidity compiler plugin then disable optimization.

Comment: Please not that I am using old remix interface, my original contract was much complicated which consumes 6500000 gas with the same construction. When I remove construction I was able to deploy my contract but I cannot if I set storage on the construction. @Badr Bellaj♦

Comment: try to change the compiler

Comment: I have tried `5.10` but still facing with the same error @Badr Bellaj♦

Comment: Which chain are you using?

Comment: I am using a `Proof-of-Authority` private chain that is generated via geth clique, please see https://github.com/ebloc/eBlocPOA @Badr Bellaj♦

Comment: With new remix interface I can deploy if I disable optimization but `owner` does not altered and remains as `0x` when I call `set()` I also face with the `gas estimation failure` @Badr Bellaj♦

Comment: try to deploy in the testnet maybe your poa is faulty. I've faced a similar problem  with geth/POA so i shifted to parity/POA

Comment: I am able to fix by using `solidity ^0.5.0` instead of its higher version and update the miners' geth version to `1.8.23`. Any contract with higher `solidity ^0.5.0` fail on gas if a storage variable is updated no matter what @Badr Bellaj♦